# Why all my iphone contacts aren't synced with Ubuntu One Contacts?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, iphone, contacts

I have more than 100 contacts on my iphone. When i sync with Ubuntu One App, only 44 contacts appears in Ubuntu One ... What is the problem ?
What can I do to have all my contacts sync ?

Comment: Ubuntu is trying to tell you 56 of those contacts are bad influences :P

Answer (score 2):

We've been seeing problems with contact syncing on iphone and nokias for a while now, and have been chasing these cases individually. The problem is, with our current infrastructure, it's usually hard to reproduce and fix.
While we continue trying to resolve each case individually, we've started to look into more in-depth solutions that provide a nicer debugging environment.

More on this within the next few months.

In the mean time, I'd suggest you wipe out the contacts database (hop in irc on freenode, #ubuntuone and we'll help you do that), so you can start fresh.

I'm sorry about the troubles you're having, we've been investing a lot of time into fixing the core problems.